# Mouse stops working in each application (separately) after 5 seconds

Tags: gnome, mouse, 22.04

Very strange issue. Every time I open a new application, the mouse works fine for about 5 seconds. Then it stops working. I can still see the cursor moving, but clicks or scrolls don't register.

I am on Ubuntu 22 with default installation. I am using a Logitech wireless mouse but I have tried with 3 other mouses and the issue persists. I am open to changing display manager, anything, I just want my computer to be usable. I have even tried changing display manager and it didn't work. I appreciate your help

Comment: Open `system monitor`, and check that your computer is not out of cpu, memory etc.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański I fixed this by changing from Wayland to X display

Comment: Ok, but I use Logitech mouse M185 on Wayland without trouble.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański I am sure my computer isn't out of resources since I'm running PS2 emulator and such on here. As I said, I don't think it was the mouse causing the issue since I had tried multiple mouses

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing from Wayland to X display server